# Background Fetch plugin not working on ios

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am using [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/) plugin for Ionic app for running my app in background and perform some tasks.

**I've achieved this on Android and its working good.**

BUT on IOS I am unable to use background mode as it provides my app exactly 30sec of background running-time and kills the app after this. For this in case, I use [cordova-plugin-background-fetch](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-fetch/) plugin.

The problem is it says

> Error initializing background fetch – "plugin_not_installed"

but ‘ionic plugin add’ says already installed..

My code:

```
 const config: BackgroundFetchConfig = {
   stopOnTerminate: false, // Set true to cease background-fetch from operating after user "closes" the app. Defaults to true.
 };

 backgroundFetch.configure(config)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Background Fetch initialized');

        this.backgroundFetch.finish();

    })
    .catch(e => console.log('Error initializing background fetch', e))
```

Comment: try to re-install the app

Comment: done it several times

Answer (score 0):

You must write backgroundFetch with Capital => BackgroundFetch

My Code:

```
BackgroundFetch.configure(fetchCallback, failureCallback, {
minimumFetchInterval: 15,
});
```